# Uniform Glivenko-Cantelli classes of functions, examples

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, big-list, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of measurable functions $X\to\Bbb{R}$. We say that $\mathcal{F}$ is a [uniform Glivenko-Cantelli class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem#Glivenko.E2.80.93Cantelli_class) if:
$$
\sup_{P\in \Delta X} \sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} | P_n f - Pf | \to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$,
where $\Delta X$ is the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$, $P_n$ are the empirical probability measures, and $Pf$ means the expectation:
$$
\int_X f\, dP\;.
$$

It is important that the convergence happens *uniformly in $P$*. (Have I understood correctly?)

Now, can someone give me examples and counterexamples of such a class? Also a reference (containing examples) would be welcome.
In particular, I would like examples where $X$ is *not* a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: In what sense the first expression converges to 0?

Comment: @d.k.o. If I have understood correctly, almost surely. But I'm not completely sure (no pun intended).

Comment: a.s. with respect to what measure? Also in the wiki article, $\mathcal{F}$ is uniform G-C if:
$$
\sup_{P\in \Delta X}\mathbb{E}[\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} | P_n f - Pf |]\to 0
$$